# How do I float image to right of Android button?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to set up buttons that have an icon in the far right of the button.
I have so far got the following:

```
<style name="MenuButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">60dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:drawableRight">@drawable/arrow_icon</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">170dip</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_menu_btn_bg</item>
</style>
```

However this only puts the image to the right of the text within the button, but I need it to be at the very right of the button no matter how much text is in the button.

So far I have just pushed it to the right using the drawablePadding but this will not work as I am going to be creating these buttons dynamically and wont know how much padding I will require.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:minHeight="60dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
   />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the `Button` class and draw the image yourself. Normally I would avoid using `android:drawableRight` and define a custom XML attribute, but for simplicity I'm instead going to "steal" the drawableRight that you've given it.

```
public class MyButton extends Button {
    private Drawable rightDrawable;
    private Rect bounds;

    /* do this for the other 2 constructors as well */
    public MyButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        bounds = new Rect();

        Drawable[] drawables = getCompoundDrawables();
        rightDrawable = drawables[2];
        if (rightDrawable != null) {
            // we are going to draw this drawable, so remove it from the superclass'
            // drawables
            setCompoundDrawables(drawables[0], drawables[1], null, drawables[3]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        if (w != oldW || h != oldh) {
            /* 
             * View's size changed, recalculate drawable bounds
             *
             * Do some math here to figure out where exactly the drawable should
             * be drawn. Make sure to take into account the drawable's intrinsic
             * height (use getIntrinsicHeight()), as well as the top, bottom, and
             * right padding of this button (use getPaddingLeft(), etc.)
             *
             * For the sake of not leading you astray with code that may not work,
             * I've not attempted those calculations. Eventually, you would call...
             */

             rect.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (rightDrawable != null) {
            rightDrawable.setBounds(rect);
            rightDrawable.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```